# A 0.5-approximation of max cut

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Describe a randomized algorithm which, for a given graph G = (V, E), finds a partition
V = V1 ∪ V2 that satisfies

|E(V1, V2)|≥1/2max|E(U1, U2)|,

where the maximum is over all partitions V = U1 ∪ U2.

To recall the terminology, consider a graph G = (V, E). For a given partition of the set
of vertices V into two subsets V1 and V2, the cut E(V1, V2) is defined as the number of edges that connect vertices from V1 to vertices from V2.

What should I do?(